# Why "Pairing Dialog" should be called this way?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-bluetooth, pairing

I've found this code to call Pairing Dialog:

```
Method createBondMethod = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice").getMethod("createBond");
createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
```

Can anyone explain, why reflection is used?

Comment: are you seriouswith that question?

Comment: sorry in the first place you asked why you called the method this way. i misunderstood you and thought you were looking for a good explaination why you chose that name